# How to create an infrastructure for node endpoint resolution on a multi-node network

Tags: go-ethereum, quorum, networking

I'm building a multi node private ethereum network with Quorum. I would like to give users of it a single url, like https://eth.domain.com, to connect to.

At the moment, `eth.domain.com` resolves to a single node. If that node is down, nobody could connect to the network even if other nodes are up. Is there any "standard" mechanism in place in Ethereum networks to support such a scenario, apart from using Infura?

First possible solution that came to my mind is to use [Round robin DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS), but this approach has drawbacks and doesn't prevent to be directed to a node that is down.

Another possible solution would probably be to use a load balancer that checks specific node health and direct traffic only to healthy ones. In this case I don't have any experience, so I would appreciate any hints on how to implement it. Of course this would become then the new [SPOF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_point_of_failure), but this seems easier to manage than single eth nodes that could "easily" get offline. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Never used it, but this seems promising: https://github.com/emeraldpay/dshackle